# ¿Cómo cambiar formato de números en visual basic?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Que tal... Disculpen, tengo un problema al guardar un valor en una base de datos desde visual basic y lo que pasa es que calcúlo un valor y el resultado es un número decimal, pero el número devuelto está separado por una coma y al guardarlo en la base de datos me da error. Lo que yo quisiera es mandar el valor pero separando los decimales por punto.
Ayuda por favor!

Este es el código:

**Este es el código de la tabla:**

```
create table Credito(
    id_credito int primary key identity,
    id_cliente int,
    id_Usuario int, 
    concepto varchar(40) not null,
    descripcion varchar(150) not null,
    cantidad_credito float not null,
    fecha_inicio date not null,
    tipo_cuota varchar(10) not null,
    fecha_fin date not null,
    cantidad_cuotas int not null,
    cantidad_mensual float not null,
    estado_credito char(1) not null,
    estado_mora int not null,
    numero_credito int,
    saldo float,
    check (estado_credito='C' or estado_credito='P'),
    check (estado_mora=1 or estado_mora=0),
    check (tipo_cuota='quincenal' or tipo_cuota='mensual'),
    constraint fk_ic foreign key(id_cliente) references Cliente,
    constraint fk_iu foreign key(id_Usuario) references Usuario
);
```

**Esta es la clase Datos en donde se encuentran las funciones**

```
Public Class Datos
    Dim conex As New SqlConnection
    Dim conectar As String = "Data Source=Desktop-sigtqcf\myserver;Initial Catalog=ProyectoFinal2;Integrated Security=True"
    Public Sub New()
        Try
            conex.ConnectionString = conectar
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub

//Esta es la función que utilizo para actualizar los registros
    Public Sub Actualizar(tabla As String, campos_valores As String, condicion As String)
        Try
            conex.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update " & tabla & " set " & campos_valores & " where " & condicion, conex)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Finally
            conex.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Y esta es la función con la que actualizo los datos al presionar Clic en un botón**

```
Public Class Pagos
    Dim obj as New Datos
    Public Sub ActualizarPago()
        If meses >= 1 Then
            cantMora = meses * precioMora **PrecioMora equivale a 2.5**
            tabla = "Credito"
            campos_valores = "Saldo=" & cantMora + saldoPend
            condicion = "numero_credito=" & numero_factura
            obj.Actualizar(tabla, campos_valores, condicion)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**obj** es una instancia de una clase, que es en donde tengo las funciones para administrar los datos...

**Actualizar** es la función que utilizo y le paso como parámetros el nombre de la tabla que quiero actualizar a los campos y los valores que van a tener y la condición que se debe cumplir para que actualice los datos.

Al tratar de insertar el valor me da error se ve que lo interpreta como si estuviera insertando dos valores diferentes debido a que está separado por esa coma...

Las variables *meses*, *cantMora*, *tabla*, *campos_valores*, *condicion* están declaradas en un módulo.

Comment: ¿Manda el código con el que estás guardando en la base de datos?
¿Qué base de datos estás usando?
¿Te refieres a VB.NET o VB6?

Comment: Estoy utilizando VB.Net y SQL Server 2012, ya está el código en la pregunta... Yo considero que el formato me lo da así debido a la configuración de la PC, pero el problema está en que si lo utilizo en otra PC con la misma configuración no voy a poder utilizar el programa.

Comment: Muy importante: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Por ejemplo, ¿de donde viene `meses`, `precioMora`? ¿Qué es `obj`? ¿Como funciona `obj.Actualizar`? Por ahora, son misterios...

Comment: meses lo obtengo segun el tiempo transcurrido, y preciomora es un valor constante que equivale a 2.5

Comment: @Daniel: Gracias por agregar informacion. Pero esto no es [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  El poner el codigo con su contexto apropiado simplifica el que podamos darte ayuda. En este momento, todavía hay muchas interrogantes. Por ejemplo, yo no puedo estar seguro de cuales son los tipos de tus variables. Aun no sé como está escrito el método `Actualizar`, y puede que el problema se tenga que resolver allí.  Se necesita el contexto debido para tener el cuadro completo. Vale la pena examinar el enlace que te puse.

Comment: Ok, gracias... En un momento lo arreglo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días, lo que tienes que hacer es convertir en String el float y después de eso hacer un `Replace`

Casteo:

[Aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) te dejo las funciones para casteo en Visual Basic

Replace:

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo del replace.

```
Dim oldString As String = "32,3"
' Returns "Shipping List".
Dim newString As String = Replace(TestString, ",", ".")
```

Entonces lo que harías es reemplazar la coma por el punto.

Comment: eso es una mala idea... prueba a setear la cultura correcta a tu app y no tendrás que hacer esos replace.

Comment: Hola, gracias a todos por su ayuda... Pero ya lo solucioné de una forma similar a la del ejemplo de replace... Y no sé de que manera adaptarlo a lo de la cultura de la app.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer tu problema tiene que ver con la cultura de tu aplicación. una opción es cuando pases el dato a numérico (aplica para todos los tipos) lo haces con parse y además le agregas la cultura a tu parse... ahora la opción definitiva(y solo si tu apoyo no es multicultura)  para no estar pendiente de la cultura en todo momento es setearle la cultura que necesites al hilo de ejecución actual de tu app